# Problems with FULL OUTER JOIN in MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, full-outer-join

So this is my query

```
SELECT user_items.userid, users.username
FROM user_items
FULL OUTER JOIN users ON user_items.userid = users.username
```

And I get the limit 0,25 error.
Could you please help me to see what I did wrong?

Comment: There isn't a full join of any sort in mysql try searching mysql full join for alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke I was stupid didn't know dat mysql doesn't have a full join